# Django different set of permissions for a user

Tags: django, permissions

In my project a user and office have many to many relationship and each user may have different roles in different offices hence he has different set of permissions how can I achieve this in django, should I use object-level permissions and set permissions in the through model between office and user or can I use the django's built in `Permission` model and have a permissions field in the through model and I don't think using groups is the nice solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need per object level permission for your project, Use [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) Then you can assign permissions on object level (say particular office) for the given user.

```py
>>> from guardian.models import UserObjectPermission
>>> user = User.objects.get(first_name='foo')
>>> office = Office.objects.get(name='bar')
>>> UserObjectPermission.objects.assign_perm('entry', user, obj=office)
<UserObjectPermission: office | foo | entry>
>>> jack.has_perm('entry', office)
True
```